# How to display record of the logged in user in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, find, record

UserController

```
public function profile()
{
   $this->set('profile', $this->User->find('all'));
}
```

profile.ctp

```
<?php
echo $profile['User']['name'];  // Where user is the model and name is the name field  in db.
?>
```

I know i am doing something wrong but i could not find any good solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function profile(){
   $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a query.
You have already the User logged if you have

> Auth

in your Appcontroller in $components like:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                )
            )
        ),
    );
```

In your controller now you have the variable with the authenticated user in this mode:

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));
```

You can make a query like this to retrieve in your database the record of the logged user:

```
this->set('profile', $this->User->find('all', array('recursive' => 1,
                    'conditions' => array('User.id' =>  $this->Auth->user()))));
```

Comment: And how we are going to echo it in view?

Comment: in view now you have the record, try to make a var_dump($profile) and you can see all fields. But if you want try: echo $profile['User']['name']; or echo $profile[0]['User']['name']; I don't know how is your array after depends of your relationship between model,

Answer (score 0):

```
public function profile()
{
   $this->set('profile', CakeSession::read('Auth.User'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function profile()
{

    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    $this->set('profile', $this->User->find('all',
        array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$user['id']))));
}
```

Comment: the user is already logged in... you don;t need to select again the same user... you already are passing the same data you have in the session in conditions array..

Answer (score 0):

What actually i did in my controller is

```
   public function profile()
{
   $id=$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
   $this->set('profile', $this->User->findByid($id));

}
```

and its working :). Thank you all for clearing the logic.